# sbt does not differenciate between flags given to test runners

Tags: sbt

Currently:

- Sbt has multiple test runners: scalaTest, junit-interface, etc..
- Each test runner has it's own set of flags ([scalaTest flags](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner), [junit-interface flags](https://github.com/sbt/junit-interface)).
- You can pass flags through sbt to the test runners, for example:

  `$ sbt '<project>/test-only * -- -f <out_file>'` (-f is a scalaTest flag)

However, the flags seem to be passed to all test runners, even if a flag is not compatible with all test runners.

I'm also experiencing behavior contrary to what I found in the documentation. ScalaTest says the `-v` flag will "*print the ScalaTest version*" and junit-interface says it will "*Log "test run started" / "test started" / "test run finished" events on log level "info" instead of "debug".*" Instead ScalaTest throws an unrecognised flag exception.

`$ sbt '<project>/test-only * -- -v'`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument unrecognized by ScalaTest's Runner: -v
    at org.scalatest.tools.ArgsParser$.parseArgs(ArgsParser.scala:425)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Framework.runner(Framework.scala:929)
    ...
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (elasticSearchDriver/test:testOnly) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument unrecognized by ScalaTest's Runner: -v
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Aug 15, 2017 11:12:56 AM
```

#### Question:

What is the actual underlying behavior of the flags passed to the test runners through sbt? Is there a bit of documentation that explains what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

By looking at SBT (0.13.x) we eventually get to a part where:

```
  def inputTests(key: InputKey[_]): Initialize[InputTask[Unit]] = inputTests0.mapReferenced(Def.mapScope(_ in key.key))
  private[this] lazy val inputTests0: Initialize[InputTask[Unit]] =
    {
      val parser = loadForParser(definedTestNames)((s, i) => testOnlyParser(s, i getOrElse Nil))
      Def.inputTaskDyn {
        val (selected, frameworkOptions) = parser.parsed
        val s = streams.value
        val filter = testFilter.value
        val config = testExecution.value

        implicit val display = Project.showContextKey(state.value)
        val modifiedOpts = Tests.Filters(filter(selected)) +: Tests.Argument(frameworkOptions: _*) +: config.options
        val newConfig = config.copy(options = modifiedOpts)
        val output = allTestGroupsTask(s, loadedTestFrameworks.value, testLoader.value, testGrouping.value, newConfig, fullClasspath.value, javaHome.value, testForkedParallel.value, javaOptions.value)
        val taskName = display(resolvedScoped.value)
        val trl = testResultLogger.value
        val processed = output.map(out => trl.run(s.log, out, taskName))
        Def.value(processed)
      }
    }
```

Notice this line: `Tests.Filters(filter(selected)) +: Tests.Argument(frameworkOptions: _*) +: config.options`

By reading this I deduce that sbt passes the arguments you pass to it to all the underlying testing frameworks.

## Solution

Don't pass test framework flags in your commands. Configure them in your `*.sbt` files like:

`testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaCheck, "-f")`

[Documentation on test framework arguments](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html#Test+Framework+Arguments)